# Retrieving properties from custom MKAnnotation subclasses from mapView.annotations

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I want to keep annotations that match an `id` property stored inside an `MKAnnotation` subclass. Inside of `regionDidChangeAnimated` I'm looping through `self.mapView.annotations` and checking their `id`, but it's always `nil`.

Does this have something to do with an object lifecycle I'm not understanding? Once the point gets added to the map, is my annotation object transformed somehow? Is there any way to get these stored values to do what I'm hoping?

Comment: MKAnnotation is a protocol, so I don't think you mean "subclass".

Comment: I meant `MKPointAnnotation`. My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely works. You're probably not setting your `id` like you think, or you're checking `mapView.annotations` before setting your `id`s. One easy way to check is to use the `didSet` callback on your `id` property, and also log when you access `mapView.annotations`.

Comment: You were right. I definitely was not setting my `id`. Always the easiest thing.

Comment: I'd rather have it easy than complex. :)